# Create a Tooltip Out from arbitrary HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I am trying to create a tooltip on a web page.  I want the user to be able to roll over a link, and when they do, display arbitrary html.  In this case, its a simple table, containing some meta data.  I have tried using `jquery.tools`, but I am not sure how to use it correctly.  Here is the idea:

```
<a id="foo">FOO</a>
<div id="tooltip-content">
    I am visible when the user hovers over FOO
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>Foo</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Value</td>
         <td>Waka waka</td>
       </tr>
       ....
    </table>
</div>
```

When the user hovers over the link text FOO, I want the div and its content to become visible, floating near the mouse, I don't care if its above, below, left or right of the link text.  It just needs to work.  What is the simplest / best way to do this?  I don't think I can use the title attribute of the link since I want to support an html table, is that correct?  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic stuff, really.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MqcMM/.  The reason the table and the link are wrapped in a container is to allow hovering over the table once it is displayed.

HTML:

```
<div id = "container">
    <a id="foo" href = "#">FOO</a>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Foo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Waka waka</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}

#container > table {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: none;
}

#container > table td {
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    padding: 2px;
}

#container:hover > table {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks, the only thing that I need to figure out how to do with this is how to make it so that the hover area of the container is just the link, and not the size of the whole table.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that.  Here's another solution using jquery.  I decided to use this as the solution for the arbitrary tooltip.  Also instead of the word INFO, I am using an "info" icon.  `<a href="#" onmouseover="$(this).next().show()" onmouseout="$(this).next().hide()">INFO</a><div class="tool-tip-holder">tooltip stuff</div>` and in the style section `.tool-tip-holder { position: absolute; display: none }`

Comment: @DRD but this affects any other table in the table. How can I not affect any other table I have in the file that are not to be used as tooltips?